# how to setup remote host for jenkins parameterized remote trigger plugin

Tags: plugins, jenkins

How do you setup the remote host field for Jenkins Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin? [The documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Remote+Trigger+Plugin) doesn't seem clear to me, and [this explanatory blog post](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/jenkins-parameterized-remote-trigger-plugin/) has some Jenkins UI features that I can't locate.

[This article](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/jenkins-parameterized-remote-trigger-plugin/) suggests going to *Manage Jenkins > Configure Credentials* to add a Domain, but when I go there I see no "Add Domain" button:

[image]

[The plugin wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Remote+Trigger+Plugin) shows screenshots of a section on a page labelled "Parameterized Remote Trigger Configuration". How do I view this section in Jenkins, where is it? I thought it might be in *Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins*, but there is no "Manage" or "Configure" button there:

[image]

How do I add a "Host" to my Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin so that I can use it in a Jenkins job?

[image]

Comment: Ok, I am facing the timeout issue when connecting to the remote server. I tried using the job import plugin which retrieves the jobs from remote server so I can tell that it is not a firewall/network issue. Here is the screen output: Triggering this remote job: editlib Not checking if the remote job editlib is building. This job is build #[30] on the remote server. Triggering remote job now. Connection to remote server failed, waiting for to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt. Retry attempt #1 out of 5 It keeps going on till 5 retries and fails. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: I strongly disagree with the down vote. There is an explanation at http://www.tothenew.com/blog/jenkins-parameterized-remote-trigger-plugin/ that is far more comprehensive than the plugin wiki page which I also struggled with.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: The official Parameterized Remote Plugin has gone stale and may not fully work. sap-production appears to be maintaining a much more up-to-date version [here](https://github.com/sap-production/parameterized-remote-trigger-plugin). You can install it on your instance by cloning the repo then running `mvn package`. Then install the `./target/Parameterized-Remote-Trigger.hpi` file using *Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins > Advanced (tab) > Upload Plugin*

It appears that the Jenkins UI has changed over time. Here is how it works now.

## Add The Domain

On the left sidebar of the main Jenkins UI, click *Credentials > System > Add domain*

[image]

Name the domain whatever you like, then click *Add > Hostname*

[image]

Fill in the IP or hostname of the remote Jenkins instance in "Includes"

[image]

## Set Up Credentials

The previous step leaves you on a page with an "Add Credentials" button. Click that. If you can't find it, then you can locate it from the main view via: Credentials > System > *Your Domain*

[image]

If not already selected, then select "Username with password". Choose a scope.

Fill in all the fields as shown. I personally recommend creating a new user on the remote Jenkins and generating an API token and using that here, but you could also just generate an API token for your own user. Click OK.

[image]

## Configure Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin

From the main Jenkins page click *Manage Jenkins > Configure System*, then scroll down to the *Parameterized Remote Trigger Configuration* section and click *Add*.

Fill out at least the *Authentication* and *Remote address and port* properties, then click Save.

[image]

## Add Build Step In Job

Open an existing Jenkins job or create a new one, scroll down to the Build section, and add the build step *Trigger a remote parameterized job*:

[image]

Select your host, and fill the rest of the values in.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is well documented on the [plugin's wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Remote+Trigger+Plugin).  See the "System configuration option" section.  If you're having trouble with one of the fields specifically, please add more detail to your question.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was somewhere in the Manage Jenkins but couldn't locate it earlier.

Comment: I disagree. It is not well documented. The question should not have been voted down. It is totally legitimate. The "System configuration option" section displays a screen shot with drop down menu to select from a list of  pre-configured build servers. It does not specify how to add those build servers in first place. I am wrestling with this problem at the moment.

Comment: A much more comprehensive guide is available ...http://www.tothenew.com/blog/jenkins-parameterized-remote-trigger-plugin/